# Using a User Defined Function in a View

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I wrote the code for a View which needs to call a user defined function which returns a table to join with it. The problem here is passing the parameter that this functions needs straight out of my view.

Below is the code of my view:

```
select
    GG.Gid,
    GG.StockType StockType,
    COALESCE(STC.Contract, 0) ContractId,
    COALESCE(C.[$Refex], null) ContractRefex,
    ST.[$Refex] StockTypeRefex
from 
(
    select
        G.Gid,
        coalesce(max(G.GEStockType), max(G.EAStockType)) StockType--,
        --case when coalesce(G.GEStockType, G.EAStockType) is null then null else coalesce(G.GEStartDate, G.EAStartDate) end StartDate
    from
    (
        select
            G.Gid, SI.StockType EAStockType, SI.[Date] EAStartDate, null GEStockType, null GEStartDate
        from Goods G
        inner join SiteIn SI on G.SiteIn=SI.[$Id]

        union

        select G.Gid, null EAStockType, null EAStartDate, GE.StockType, GE.EventOn
        from 
        (
            Select
                GE.Gid,  max(GE.EventOn) GEStartDate
            from GoodsEvent GE
            where GE.IsDeleted=0 and GE.[Type]='ST' and GE.EventOn < GETDATE()
            group by Gid 
        ) G
        inner join GoodsEvent GE on GE.Gid=G.Gid
            and G.GEStartDate=GE.EventOn
            and GE.[Type]='ST'
    ) G
    group by G.Gid
) GG
left outer join StockType ST on ST.[$Id]=GG.StockType
inner join (SELECT * FROM [dbo].StockTypeContractGetClosestStartDate(ST.[$Id]))
 STC on  GG.StockType = STC.[Parent]
 inner join Contract C On STC.Contract = C.[$Id]
```

And this is the code of my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION StockTypeContractGetClosestStartDate
(
    @ParentId int
)
RETURNS  @StockTypeContract TABLE 
(
    [StartDate] [DateTime] null,
    [Parent] [int] not null,
    [Contract] [int] null
)
AS
BEGIN

 INSERT @StockTypeContract 
    SELECT TOP 1 STC.StartDate , STC.[$ParentId] , STC.Contract
     from StockTypeContract STC
        where STC.[$ParentId] = @ParentId AND STC.StartDate <= GETDATE() 
        order by STC.StartDate desc

    RETURN
END
```

It gives me an error when trying to pass ST.[$Id] to my function, the error is "The multi-part identifier ST.$Id could not be bound".

Is there any work-around for this?

Comment: There is no reason for this to be a multi statement function. You should make it inline as these can be optimised better. i.e. use the syntax `CREATE FUNCTION StockTypeContractGetClosestStartDate (@ParentId int) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (SELECT TOP...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually needs [CROSS or OUTER APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx). And [from SO too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join)

```
....
left outer join StockType ST on ST.[$Id]=GG.StockType
CROSS APPLY
[dbo].StockTypeContractGetClosestStartDate(ST.[$Id])
...
```

(I've simplified parenthesis here BTW, probably wrongly)

Your problem is "get a resultset from StockTypeContractGetClosestStartDate **per** ST.[$Id]

Comment: Well, CROSS APPLY does what I need except that this ST.[$Id] can eventually be null and right now I'm not being able to return rows where this row is null (meaning that there's no stocktype for that given row). Do you have any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: @Hallaghan will `OUTER APPLY` do what you need?

Comment: OUTER APPLY returned exactly the same result set as CROSS APPLY did. Both aren't returning rows where the stockType is null, thus making the contract column null as well. The contract column is only filled when there's a stockType associated.

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing the last 2 statements like so:

OUTER APPLY [dbo].StockTypeContractGetClosestStartDate(GG.StockType) STC
  LEFT JOIN Contract C On STC.Contract = C.[$Id]

Thanks for all the help and also from what I learned here.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct your only inserting one record in the return table of your function, if that is the case then you can rebuild the function as a scalar function, this returns only one value and should solve the multi-part problem.

At the moment your trying to join with a possible "multi valued id".

see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx for the scalar function