# Group By & Get Count of 1 to many table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE `purchases` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `totalAmount` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `purchaseDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and another table that stores all the details of the purchases (eg.line items)

```
CREATE TABLE `purchase_items` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `purchaseId` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `itemId` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`purchaseId`) REFERENCES purchases(id)
)
```

I get the total purchases on any given day this way

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(purchaseDate, '%m-%d-%Y') AS date,
COUNT(id) AS totalPurchases
FROM purchases
GROUP BY DATE(purchaseDate)
```

This gives me a result as such

```
date        totalPurchases
11-18-2010  5
11-19-2010  10
11-20-2010  10
```

How will I perform a query such that it returns me something like this

```
date        totalPurchases  totalItems
11-18-2010  5               20
11-19-2010  10              30
11-20-2010  10              25
```

So I will still be grouping by date but I need to perform a join on 'purchase_items' and get the total number of item that were linked to the

- 5 Purchases on 11-18-2010
- 10 Purchases on 11-19-2010
- 10 Purchases on 11-20-2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(p.purchasedate, '%m-%d-%Y'),
         COUNT(p.id) AS totalPurchases,
         COUNT(pi.itemid) AS totalItems
    FROM PURCHASES p
    JOIN PURCHASE_ITEMS pi ON pi.purchaseid = p.id
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(p.purchasedate, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

If it's possible that there's no relation to the PURCHASE_ITEMS tables, use:

```
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(p.purchasedate, '%m-%d-%Y'),
          COUNT(p.id) AS totalPurchases,
          COUNT(pi.itemid) AS totalItems
     FROM PURCHASES p
LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_ITEMS pi ON pi.purchaseid = p.id
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(p.purchasedate, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: Kidnly tell me, if there is any benifit if I use `cross apply` for first statement (see my answer)?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: MySQL (as the question is tagged) [doesn't support `CROSS APPLY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) - that's TSQL/SQL Server syntax.  Beyond that, your answer lies with this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join) and [explainextended article](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/).

Answer (score 1):

Edit -

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(A.purchaseDate, '%m-%d-%Y') AS date,
COUNT(A.id) AS totalPurchases,count(B.id)
FROM purchases A LEFT OUTER JOIN purchaseitems B on A.id = B.purchaseid
GROUP BY DATE(purchaseDate)
```

Comment: Somehow inner join does not work if some purchases don't have items. I know it's ridiculous that purchases would not have items, but this was just an example I came up with. My original 1-to-many table could actually not have any line items. Thanks though!

Comment: Oh that should be fine, you can use a left outer join instead of an inner join. Will update my answer in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select p.purchasedate, sum(p.id), items.items_count
from purchases p
cross apply
(
   select count(id) [items_count]
   from purchase_items
   where purchaseId = p.id
)items
group by p.purchasedate, items.items_count
```

Comment: I haven't tried this as the whole cross apply thing seems a bit too complicated for me at the moment. Thanks though, definitely something I might want to try out in the future.