# Select Top 1 From a Table For Each Id in another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table Structure is:

```
create table fruit (
  id int identity(1,1),
  name varchar(max)
)

create table fruit_allocation (
  id int identity(1,1),
  fruit_id int references fruit(id),
  customer_id int references store(id),
  amount float,
)

create table measurement (
  fruit_allocation_id int references fruit_allocation(id),
  measurement_date datetime,
  measurement float,
)
```

Each fruit can be allocated to more than one customer creating a fruit_allocation record. Each fruit_allocation record can have multiple measurements.

I want to select the latest measurement for each fruit_allocation given a fruit id

So far I have the following:

```
select * 
  from measurement 
 where fruit_allocation_id in (select id 
                                 from fruit_allocation 
                                where fruit_id = 10)
```

This returns all measurements for that fruit, I want to just return 1 measurement per fruit_allocation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can [CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx)

```
select a.*, m.*
from fruit_allocation a
cross apply (
    select top 1 *
    from measurement m
    where m.fruit_allocation_id = a.id
    order by m.measurement_date desc
) m
where a.fruit_id = 10
```

Comment: You might find this discussion of APPLY vs. JOIN interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1139160/4794

Comment: @Don The "vs" only applies if the JOIN will work at all. In this case, a JOIN cannot work out a `correlated TOP 1`. But thanks for linking to BOL and for a good read

Comment: There are more creative ways of using a join to solve this problem. (See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073089/select-top-1-from-a-table-for-each-id-in-another-table/5073172#5073172 ) However, it's interesting to learn about APPLY, and it sounds like it might be more efficient in this case.

Comment: BTW, BOL? Is it Book O' Learnin'?

Comment: @Don - abbreviation for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx **B** ooks **O** n **L** ine

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005+

```
With RankedMeasurements As
    (
    Select M.fruit_allocation_id
        , M.measurement_date
        , M.measurement
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By M.fruit_allocation_id 
                                Order By M.measurement_date Desc ) As Rnk
    From measurement As M
    Where Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From fruit_allocation As FA1
                    Where FA1.id = M.fruit_allocation_id
                        And FA1.fruit_id = 10
                    )   
    )
Select RM.fruit_allocation_id
    , RM.measurement_date
    , RM.measurement
From RankedMeasurements As RM
Where Rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a subquery to find the latest measurement for each allocation, then join to that subquery as if it were a real table.

```
select * from measurement meas
join
        (
        SELECT  fruit_allocation_id,
                MAX(measurement_date) as max_date
        FROM    measurement meas2
        JOIN    fruit_allocation alloc
        ON      alloc.id = meas2.fruit_allocation_id
        where fruit_id = 10
        ) max_meas
on      meas.fruit_allocation_id = max_mes.fruit_allocation_id
and     meas.measurement_date = max_meas.max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

select * 
  from measurement m
 where measurement_date = (select top 1 measurement_date from measurement m1
                where m1.fruit_allocation_id = m.fruit_allocation_id
                order by measurement_date desc)
 And 
 fruit_allocation_id in (select id 
                                 from fruit_allocation 
                                where fruit_id = 3)

Comment: but it seems cross apply not so heavy a and can get data from [fruit_allocation] ...