# Cross apply vs. cursor - syntax and differences

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server.

Can any one help me organize the syntax and difference between

`cursor` and `cross apply`' ?

Update: my intention is:

I have one user-SP_1 which gets a varchar "id" as param. I have built another user-SP_2 that gets manay "ids", parse them and then I want to send them to user-SP_1 in a loop.

Comment: Those are totally different things - you're comparing an apple to a Space Shuttle..... where to start with the differences....... maybe some context would help - what are you trying to do where you have cursors vs. cross apply as options??

Comment: I have one user-SP_1 which gets a varchar "id" as param. I have built another user-SP_2 that gets manay "ids", parse them and then I want to send them to user-SP_1 in a loop.

Comment: @EladBenda: Can you add the structures of the relevant tables to your question? It sounds as though a relatively simple query could be written to return the required data, but in order to do so we would need to know the table structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursors allow you to loop through data one record at a time.  They are generally discouraged because they are ridiculously slow compared to set based operations, and I would venture to say that the need for them is most often caused by a poor database design.  They are nonetheless necessary sometimes though.

Here is a good SO page on Cross Apply: [When should I use Cross Apply over Inner Join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join)

I suspect that one of these two things isn't quite what you are thinking it is though since as marc_s said they are completely different things.  So let us know what you're trying to accomplish if you need more help.