# Fetch Previous day record using sql server using Date field

Tags: sql-server

I want to fetch `previous day` record from the table using a date field in `Sql Server`.

However I'm using the below sql statements but it's not giving any record.

```
TDTE = CAST(DATEADD(DD,-1,CURRNT_TIMESTAMP) AS DECIMAL(8,0))
```

OR

```
TDTE=CAST(DATEADD(DD,-1,GETDATE())AS DECIMAL(8,0))
```

where `TDTE` column is in `YYYYMMDD` format.

Comment: What is the column type of **TDTE** ? @Gyan05

Comment: it's a Date field but the format is e.g 20150112 etc. i.e YYYYMMDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Where TDTE  = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()), 112)
```

OR(in decimal format)

```
Where TDTE  = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()), 112)AS DECIMAL(18,0))
```

Comment: Excellent..Finally..:)  Could you please tell why that 112 used?

Comment: Its a **CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112)** will convert the date to **YYYYMMDD** format. Its already written by SQL Server. You can change to another format by changing number, for eg, **103** will convert date to **dd/mm/yyyy** format. @Gyan05

Comment: Good one didn't thought about it +1

Comment: You would have solved faster than me since u r good in queries than me. OP updated the type of column later. Anyway thank you :) @NoDisplayName

Comment: Hey friend, I have posted a question 2 days back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838045/difference-between-left-join-and-outer-apply . I didn't get a proper feedback with real time examples. Can u bring some real time examples and a good solution for my question? @NoDisplayName

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `Cast` function `Dateadd` returns `Date` not a `Integer` value. Try this.

```
Where TDTE  = Cast(DATEADD(DD,-1,GETDATE()) as Date)
```

Comment: It throws error.SqlState: 22003, ErrorCode: 8115, ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: @Gyan05 Not sure why got that error check now updated

Comment: SQL##f - SqlState: 22005, ErrorCode: 206, ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: date is incompatible with decimal...  Tried DECIMAL(8,0) in place of Date. but not getting any result also