# T-SQL - Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

Have 2 tables: `users` and `offers`.

I need to extract 3 offers for each user.

I wrote this command line:

```
SELECT TOP 10  
    sellerID, 
    Country, 
    (SELECT TOP 3 ItemID 
     FROM Items i 
     JOIN Sellers s ON s.sellerID = i.UserID 
     ORDER BY CreatedDate)
FROM 
    Sellers 
ORDER BY
    Country desc
```

Not sure if really returns what I'm looking for, but I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , > >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Can suggest a solution or a workaround?

Comment: `Not sure if really returns what I'm looking for` - no, it does not. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/86415/5203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is what you need. Please see query example:

```
SELECT TOP (10) S.SellerID, S.Country, I.ItemID
FROM dbo.Sellers AS S
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (3) I.ItemID
    FROM dbo.Items AS I
    WHERE S.SellerID = I.UserID
    ORDER BY I.CreatedDate
    ) AS I
ORDER BY S.Country DESC;
```

This query will bring you back `TOP (10)` results. If you want to get `TOP (10)` users and 3 items for each user (This means up to 30 records), use this query instead:

```
SELECT S.SellerID, S.Country, I.ItemID
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (10) S.SellerID, S.Country
    FROM dbo.Sellers AS S
    ORDER BY S.Country DESC
    ) AS S
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT TOP (3) I.ItemID
FROM dbo.Items AS I
WHERE S.SellerID = I.UserID
ORDER BY I.CreatedDate
) AS I;
```

One of it's uses is exactly what you're asking. Returning `TOP (n)` subitems. More real life examples can be found here: [Real life example, when to use OUTER / CROSS APPLY in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275132/real-life-example-when-to-use-outer-cross-apply-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You have the subquery in the select clause.  It must return 1 row there.  Try joining to it instead-

```
SELECT 
TOP 10  sellerID, 
Country, items.ItemID
from Sellers 
left join
(
   SELECT TOP 3 UserID, ItemID 
   from Items i 
   join Sellers s  
   on s.sellerID=i.UserID 
   order by CreatedDate
) items
on sellers.UserID = items.UserID
order by Country desc
```

Comment: No, this returns items.ItemID for only the first 3 UserID, I can imagine this is due to the inner clause ` "SELECT TOP 3 UserID...."`

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you have asked a `select` to output rows each containing a value for `sellerId`, `Country` and *three* values for `ItemID`.

The subquery is also not correlated with the outer query, i.e. you have a second reference to the `Sellers` table, but have done nothing to match up values with the outer query.

Assuming that you actually want the top 3 items for each of up to 10 countries, this should be close:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Sellers as Table ( SellerId Int, Country VarChar(16) );
insert into @Sellers ( SellerId, Country ) values
  ( 1, 'Canada' ), ( 2, 'Italy' ), ( 3, 'Elbonia' ), ( 4, 'Maldives' ), ( 5, 'Fiji' ),
  ( 6, 'Ecuador' ), ( 7, 'Chile' ), ( 8, 'Mexico' ), ( 9, 'Palau' ), ( 10, 'Yap' ),
  ( 11, 'Saba' );
declare @Items as Table ( ItemId Int, UserId Int, CreatedDate Date );
insert into @Items ( ItemId, UserId, CreatedDate ) values
  ( 1, 3, '20150308' ), ( 2, 3, '20150619' ), ( 3, 3, '20120908' ), ( 4, 3, '20140228' ),
  ( 2, 9, '20150308' ), ( 3, 9, '20150619' ), ( 4, 9, '20120908' ), ( 5, 9, '20140228' ),
  ( 3, 6, '20150308' ), ( 4, 6, '20150619' ), ( 4, 6, '20120908' ), ( 6, 6, '20140228' );

select * from @Sellers;
select * from @Items;

-- Show the intermediate results.
with AllSellersAndItems as
  ( select S.SellerId, S.Country, I.ItemId,
    Row_Number() over ( partition by S.SellerId order by I.CreatedDate ) as ItemSequence,
    Dense_Rank() over ( order by Country ) as SellerSequence
    from @Sellers as S inner join
      @Items as I on I.UserId = S.SellerId )
  select * from AllSellersAndItems;

-- The real query.
with AllSellersAndItems as
  ( select S.SellerId, S.Country, I.ItemId,
    Row_Number() over ( partition by S.SellerId order by I.CreatedDate ) as ItemSequence,
    Dense_Rank() over ( order by Country ) as SellerSequence
    from @Sellers as S inner join
      @Items as I on I.UserId = S.SellerId )
  select SellerId, Country, ItemId, SellerSequence, ItemSequence
    from AllSellersAndItems
    where SellerSequence <= 10 and ItemSequence <= 3
    order by Country desc
```

Answer (score 0):

this query work for you :

```
    SELECT  TOP 10  sellerID,  Country, items.ItemID
    from Sellers 
    left join Items On Items.UserID = Sellers.sellerID
                   And Items.ItemID in ( Select Top 3 I_1.ItemID From Items As I_1
                                         Where I_1.UserID = Sellers.sellerID
                                         Order by CreatedDate )
   ORDER BY Country desc
```

Comment: Thanks, This works to, but with around 100.000 Sellers and 1 Million Items takes on average 12 seconds, while the solution with 'CROSS APPLY' takes 6 seconds