# Selecting a group of dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a history table that captures updates to a certain object and, in addition to other information, captures the time this update happened. What I would like to do is `SELECT` the `MIN(LogDate)` corresponding to a certain `ActionTaken` column.

More specifically, the history table may have other (more recent) rows where `ActionTaken = 1`, but I want to capture the date `ActionTaken` *became* 1.

Example:

```
SELECT  MIN(LogDate) AS FirstActionDate
FROM    HistoryTable
WHERE   ID = 123
    AND FirstActionTaken = 1

SELECT  MIN(LogDate) AS SecondActionDate
FROM    HistoryTable
WHERE   ID = 123
    AND SecondActionTaken = 1

SELECT  MIN(LogDate) AS ThirdActionDate
FROM    HistoryTable
WHERE   ID = 123
    AND ThirdActionTaken = 1
```

This works well, and I receive the proper dates without issue. Where I'm running into trouble is then going to `select` the `MAX(LogDate)` from this group:

```
SELECT  MAX(LogDate) AS LastActionDate
FROM    HistoryTable
WHERE   ID = 123
    AND LogDate IN 
    (
            (   SELECT  MIN(LogDate) AS FirstActionDate
                FROM    HistoryTable
                WHERE   ID = 123
                    AND FirstActionTaken = 1    ),

            (   SELECT  MIN(LogDate) AS SecondActionDate
                FROM    HistoryTable
                WHERE   ID = 123
                    AND SecondActionTaken = 1   ),

            (   SELECT  MIN(LogDate) AS ThirdActionDate
                FROM    HistoryTable
                WHERE   ID = 123
                    AND ThirdActionTaken = 1    )
    )
```

This also works, but I hate doing it this way. I could save out the previous statements into variables and just `SELECT MAX()` from those; it would certainly be more readable, but what would the `JOIN` syntax look like for this query?

*Is there a way to combine the first three `SELECT` statements into one that returns all three dates and isn't an unreadable mess?*

*How can I grab the most recent `LogDate` (as a separate column) from this result set and without the (seemingly unnecessary) repeating `SELECT` statements?*

EDIT:

Here are a few links I've found in relation to the answers that have been given so far:

- [Data Normalization](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/25209)
- [Using `OUTER/CROSS APPLY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275132/real-life-example-when-to-use-outer-cross-apply-in-sql)
- [`UNPIVOT`](http://blog.devart.com/is-unpivot-the-best-way-for-converting-columns-into-rows.html) (and others)

Hopefully these will help with others looking for solutions to similar problems!

Comment: use a UNION and then you can use IN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

Based on new information that can be gleaned from OP's own answer (about how to define the latest action date), the query can be further simplified to simply this:

```
select coalesce(
         min(case when ThirdActionTaken = 1 then LogDate end),
         min(case when SecondActionTaken = 1 then LogDate end),
         min(case when FirstActionTaken = 1 then LogDate end)
       ) as LastActionDate
  from HistoryTable
 where id = 123
```

---

Unpivot can also be used:

```
 select max(ActionDate)
   from (select min(case when FirstActionTaken = 1 then LogDate end) as FirstActionDate,
                min(case when SecondActionTaken = 1 then LogDate end) as SecondActionDate,
                min(case when ThirdActionTaken = 1 then LogDate end) as ThirdActionDate
           from HistoryTable
          where id = 123) t
unpivot (ActionDate for ActionDates in (FirstActionDate, SecondActionDate, ThirdActionDate)) unpvt
```

**EDIT: Short explanation**

This answer is very similar to Gordon's in that it uses conditional aggregation to get the 3 minimum dates in one query.

So the following part of the query:

```
select min(case when FirstActionTaken = 1 then LogDate end) as FirstActionDate,
       min(case when SecondActionTaken = 1 then LogDate end) as SecondActionDate,
       min(case when ThirdActionTaken = 1 then LogDate end) as ThirdActionDate
  from HistoryTable
 where id = 123
```

...might return something like...

```
FirstActionDate   SecondActionDate   ThirdActionDate
---------------   ----------------   ---------------
     2015-01-01         2015-12-01            (null)
```

Then, the `unpivot` clause is what "unpivots" the 3 columns into a result set with 3 rows but a single column instead:

```
ActionDate
----------
2015-01-01
2015-12-01
    (null)
```

Once the results are in this format, then a simple `max` aggregate function (`select max(ActionDate)`) can be applied to get the max value of the 3 rows.

Comment: This works great, and feels much nicer than my own attempt at it :) Would you mind adding some explanation about what's happening here? Especially in relation to `UNPIVOT`. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the update on the answer - and apologies for not specifying that to begin with!

Answer (score 3):

This would be easier with a normalized data structure.  Here is one method that uses conditional aggregation to calculate the three minimum dates.  Then it takes the maximum of those values:

```
SELECT v.dt
FROM (SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN FirstActionTaken = 1 THEN LogDate END) AS d1,
             MIN(CASE WHEN SecondActionTaken = 1 THEN LogDate END) AS d2,
             MIN(CASE WHEN ThirdActionTaken = 1 THEN LogDate END) AS d3      
     FROM HistoryTable
     WHERE ID = 123
    ) ht OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT MAX(dt) as dt
     FROM (VALUES (d1), (d2), (d3) ) v(dt)
    ) v;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UNION to join the 3 queries for your IN statement.

Something like

```
SELECT
    MAX(ht1.LogDate) AS LastActionDate
FROM
    HistoryTable ht1
WHERE
    ht1.ID = 123
    AND ht1.LogDate IN (SELECT
                        MIN(LogDate) AS FirstActionDate
                    FROM
                        HistoryTable ht2
                    WHERE
                        ht2.ID = ht1.ID
                        AND ht2.FirstActionTaken = 1
                    UNION
                    SELECT
                        MIN(LogDate) AS FirstActionDate
                    FROM
                        HistoryTable ht2
                    WHERE
                        ht2.ID = ht1.ID
                        AND ht2.SecondActionTaken = 1
                    UNION
                    SELECT
                        MIN(LogDate) AS FirstActionDate
                    FROM
                        HistoryTable ht2
                    WHERE
                        ht2.ID = ht1.ID
                        AND ht2.ThirdActionTaken = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem without using PIVOT. The following code extends your initial code to store the MIN values into variables and then calculates the max value among them:

```
DECLARE @FirstActionDate  DATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @SecondActionDate DATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @ThirdActionDate  DATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @LastActionDate   DATETIME = NULL;

SELECT  @FirstActionDate = MIN(LogDate)
FROM    HistoryTable
WHERE   ID = 123
    AND FirstActionTaken = 1

SELECT  @SecondActionDate = MIN(LogDate)
FROM    HistoryTable
WHERE   ID = 123
    AND SecondActionTaken = 1

SELECT  @ThirdActionDate = MIN(LogDate)
FROM    HistoryTable
WHERE   ID = 123
    AND ThirdActionTaken = 1

-- calculate @LastActionDate as the greater from @FirstActionDate, @SecondActionDate and @ThirdActionDate. 
SET @LastActionDate = @FirstActionDate;
IF (@SecondActionDate > @LastActionDate) SET @LastActionDate = @SecondActionDate;
IF (@ThirdActionDate > @LastActionDate)  SET @LastActionDate = @ThirdActionDate;

SELECT @FirstActionDate AS [FirstActionDate]
, @SecondActionDate     AS [SecondActionDate]
, @ThirdActionDate      AS [ThirdActionDate]
, @LastActionDate       AS [LastActionDate]
```

If you want the absolute last action date, you can change the original code to just a single statement, as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(LogDate) AS [LastActionDate]
, MIN(CASE WHEN FirstActionTaken = 1  THEN LogDate ELSE NULL END) AS [FirstActionDate]
, MIN(CASE WHEN SecondActionTaken = 1 THEN LogDate ELSE NULL END) AS [SecondActionDate]
, MIN(CASE WHEN ThirdActionTaken = 1  THEN LogDate ELSE NULL END) AS [ThirdActionDate]
FROM    HistoryTable
WHERE   ID = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

My own attempt at refactoring the final `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT  MIN(ht2.LogDate) AS FirstActionDate,
        MIN(ht3.LogDate) AS SecondActionDate,
        MIN(ht4.LogDate) AS ThirdActionDate,
        COALESCE (
            MIN(ht4.LogDate),
            MIN(ht3.LogDate),
            MIN(ht2.LogDate)
        ) AS LastActionDate
FROM    HistoryTable ht
    INNER JOIN HistoryTable ht2 
        ON ht2.ID = ht.ID AND ht2.FirstActionTaken = 1
    INNER JOIN HistoryTable ht3 
        ON ht3.ID = ht.ID AND ht3.SecondActionTaken = 1
    INNER JOIN HistoryTable ht4 
        ON ht4.ID = ht.ID AND ht4.ThirdActionTaken = 1
WHERE   ht.ID = 123
GROUP BY ht.ID
```

This `JOINS` back to `HistoryTable` for each `xActionTaken` column and `SELECTS` the `MIN(LogDate)` from each. Then, we walk backwards through the results (`ThirdAction`, `SecondAction`, `FirstAction`) and return the first one we find as `LastActionTaken`.

Admittedly this is a bit messy, but I thought it would be good to show another alternative to retrieving the same data.

**Also worth noting for performance:**

After running my answer against the `UNPIVOT` and `OUTER APPLY` methods, `SSMS Execution Plan` shows that `UNPIVOT` and `OUTER APPLY` are roughly equal (taking approx. `50%` of the execution time each).

When comparing my method to either of these, my method takes approx. `88%` of the execution time, where `UNPIVOT`/`OUTER APPLY` only take `12%` - so both `UNPIVOT` and `OUTER APPLY` execute much faster (at least in this instance).

The reason that my method takes so much longer is that `SQL` does a table scan of `HistoryTable` for each time I join back to it, for a total of `4` scans. With the other two methods, this action is only performed once.

Comment: Your question never specified that `ThirdActionDate > SecondActionDate > FirstActionDate`, but your answer implies that this is always true.  That being the case, you don't need any unpivot, outer apply or joins.  The query only needs conditional aggregation with a coalesce.  I edited my answer. That should give you the best performance.