# SQL Server : how to use count

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, case

I am using this SQL Server [database](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pamelafox/ad4f6abbaac0a48aa781/raw/c72be44a1bdefcbaf8af63361f98595552131b9c/countries_by_population.sql). I am defining the following remarks for countries

```
CASE 
    WHEN density_per_sq_km > 1000 THEN 'Overpopulated'
    WHEN density_per_sq_km > 500 THEN 'above average'
    WHEN density_per_sq_km > 250 THEN 'average'
    WHEN density_per_sq_km > 50 THEN 'below average' 
    ELSE 'Underpopulated'
END as remarks
```

Now I want to count how many countries are there in each remark. How can I do that? I am using the following query but it fails

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(country) as no_of_countries,
    CASE 
        WHEN density_per_sq_km > 1000 THEN 'Overpopulated'
        WHEN density_per_sq_km > 500 THEN 'above average'
        WHEN density_per_sq_km > 250 THEN 'average'
        WHEN density_per_sq_km > 50 THEN 'below average' 
        ELSE 'Underpopulated'
    END as remarks
FROM 
    countries_by_population 
GROUP BY 
    remarks;
```

Comment: Use `COUNT(distinct country)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the group by clause you cannot use that column alias, use the case expression instead

```
SELECT
      COUNT(country) AS no_of_countries
    , CASE
            WHEN density_per_sq_km > 1000 THEN 'Overpopulated'
            WHEN density_per_sq_km > 500 THEN 'above average'
            WHEN density_per_sq_km > 250 THEN 'average'
            WHEN density_per_sq_km > 50 THEN 'below average'
            ELSE 'Underpopulated'
      END AS remarks
FROM countries_by_population
GROUP BY
      CASE
            WHEN density_per_sq_km > 1000 THEN 'Overpopulated'
            WHEN density_per_sq_km > 500 THEN 'above average'
            WHEN density_per_sq_km > 250 THEN 'average'
            WHEN density_per_sq_km > 50 THEN 'below average'
            ELSE 'Underpopulated'
      END
;
```

Comment: can you explain is there any possible way i can use the remarks in GROUP BY or ORDER BY

Comment: **You can use the alias in the ORDER BY clause.** Not the group by clause unless using a cross apply (see answer by Evaldas Buinauskas) or you can use a "derived table" (see answer by Jiri Tousek) . There is no performance penalty (at all) when re-using the case expression as I have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the query with computed column into a subquery may help you use that column:

```
SELECT remarks, COUNT(country) as no_of_countries
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN density_per_sq_km > 1000 THEN 'Overpopulated'
      WHEN density_per_sq_km > 500 THEN 'above average'
      WHEN density_per_sq_km > 250 THEN 'average'
      WHEN density_per_sq_km > 50 THEN 'below average' 
      ELSE 'Underpopulated'
    END as remarks,
    country
  FROM countries_by_population
) DT
GROUP BY remarks;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CROSS APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to assign alias to your column.

```
SELECT T.Remarks, COUNT(*) AS no_of_countries
FROM countries_by_population AS CBP
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE
            WHEN density_per_sq_km > 1000 THEN 'Overpopulated'
            WHEN density_per_sq_km > 500  THEN 'Above average'
            WHEN density_per_sq_km > 250  THEN 'Average'
            WHEN density_per_sq_km > 50   THEN 'Below average'
            ELSE 'Underpopulated'
        END
    ) AS T(Remarks)
GROUP BY T.Remarks;
```

This will create a column `Remarks` based on your density, which can be later used in `GROUP BY`.

[Tip: APPLY and Reuse of Column Aliases](http://sqlmag.com/blog/tip-apply-and-reuse-column-aliases) article explains how to use `CROSS APPLY` to create reusable column aliases in detail.

Comment: This worked but i am not yet familiar with CROSS APPLY and the use of T in that query. I am a beginner and learning SQL

Comment: @Newton You could read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275132/real-life-example-when-to-use-outer-cross-apply-in-sql there's also a link which explains how you can use it to create aliases, that can be reused. It should be a good starting point.