# Using OUTER APPLY with Codeigniter active record

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, activerecord, outer-apply

Is it possible to use SQL Server's `OUTER APPLY` with Codeignter's Active Record?

Comment: Not sure about APPLY but you can do OUTER join.. like: $this->db->join('table', 'table.id = table2.id', 'outer');

Comment: Yeah, I've used join plenty of times, but in this case I need to use APPLY. Might need to get creative with this...

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. For using Cross Apply or Outer Apply, you need to add a specific function in the file system\database\DB_query_builder.php

that being said, you can add this function (modified from join one) to said file:

```
public function apply($table, $type = '', $escape = NULL){
    if ($type !== '')
    {
        $type = strtoupper(trim($type));

        if ( ! in_array($type, array('CROSS', 'OUTER'), TRUE))
        {
            $type = 'CROSS';
        }
    }
    else{
        $type = 'CROSS';
    }

    // Extract any aliases that might exist. We use this information
    // in the protect_identifiers to know whether to add a table prefix
    $this->_track_aliases($table);

    is_bool($escape) OR $escape = $this->_protect_identifiers;

    // Do we want to escape the table name?
    if ($escape === TRUE)
    {
        $table = $this->protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);
    }

    // Assemble the APPLY statement
    $this->qb_join[] = $join = $type.' APPLY '.$table;

    if ($this->qb_caching === TRUE)
    {
        $this->qb_cache_join[] = $join;
        $this->qb_cache_exists[] = 'join';
    }

    return $this;
}
```

And then, you can using it like

```
$this->db->apply('(select * from table_a where table_a.id=table_z.fk_id) as tmp_table');
```

or something more complete like

```
$this->db->apply('(select * from table_a where table_a.id=table_z.fk_id) as tmp_table','outer',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

```
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id', 'outer');
```

Or

```
$this->db->query("SELECT column_name(s)
    FROM table1
    FULL OUTER JOIN table2
    ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;");
```

[image: 01]

[Codeigniter Query Builder](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?#selecting-data)  and [OUTER APPLY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9275865/4595675) example

---

**Possible joins with Codeigniter**
(associate with this `$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id', 'outer');`)

1. left
2. right
3. outer
4. inner
5. left outer
6. right outer