# How to add TOP 1 in query with left join in views?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbeaver

I have 3 same product in ID=42, with 3 different images. I want to take the first image from the product ID, I try adding "TOP 1", error

This is my query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW UserOrdersView
AS 
SELECT 
    u.[User_ID],
    p.Product_Name,
    p.Price, 
    o.Order_Price, 
    o.Order_ID, 
    i.[Image]
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON o.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.[User_ID]= o.[User_ID]
LEFT JOIN Product_Images  i ON i.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
WHERE o.[User_ID] = 42
```

Comment: So you get an error? Why don't you tell us what the error is? And how did you use `TOP 1`?

Comment: Please avoid images, add some sample data and expected output. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you sure the question is about SQL Server? the syntax `Create or replace` is typical in Oracle, not in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OUTER APPLY` to get top 1 image data from Product_image table based on `Product ID`.

Please check this **[Real life example, when to use OUTER / CROSS APPLY in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9275865/7009448)** stackoverflow link for more knowledge.

Please check below updated view code for your answer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW UserOrdersView
AS 
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        u.[User_ID],
        p.Product_Name,
        p.Price, 
        o.Order_Price, 
        o.Order_ID, 
        i.[Image]
    FROM Product p
    INNER JOIN Users u ON u.[User_ID]= o.[User_ID]
    LEFT JOIN Orders o ON o.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
    OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1            
            T2.[Image]
        FROM Product_Images T2
        WHERE T2.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
    ) i
    WHERE o.[User_ID] = 42

END
GO
```

Comment: Means you are getting any error or not giving you expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT 
    u.[User_ID],
    p.Product_Name,
    p.Price, 
    o.Order_Price, 
    o.Order_ID, 
    i.[Image],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.[Image] ORDER BY p.Product_Name) AS rn   
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON o.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.[User_ID]= o.[User_ID]
LEFT JOIN Product_Images  i ON i.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
)
SELECT [User_ID],Product_Name,Price,Order_Price,Order_ID,[Image] FROM cte
WHERE rn=1
```

**Put your all query inside a CTE with a new column that you will use to filter the results.
This new column is produced with ROW_NUMBER() function partitioned by Product_Name**