# How to nest multiple left join and subqueries in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I nest two subqueries and two left joins at the same time? I currently have my query (query1) as below which works perfect..  But it involves connecting two outside queries which have to be updated separtely by data date.

I want to extend query1 by applying subquery (query2) out for practice and to also update everything in one script.

NOTE:  Query is written in MS Access.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
Acct.AccountNumber
, Acct.ABCat AS Cat
, Acct.fName AS FirstName
, Acct.lName AS LastName
, Acct.Age AS Age
, o.Type, o.OFirstLoginDate
, o.OLastLoginDate
, m.Type
, m.LstDepDate AS LastDepDate
FROM 
table1 AS Acct 
LEFT JOIN 
        OB_table AS o 
        ON Acct.AccountNumber = o.AccountNumber

LEFT JOIN 
        MB_table AS m 
        ON Acct.AccountNumber = m.AccountNumber
WHERE 
Acct.Cat IN (9,12,16,17)
AND Acct.DataDate = 20200430 
AND Acct.Status = 'Open';
```

Query2 
Using Subqueries and Left Join 
I get the error

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Acct.AccountNumber = o.AccountNumber    
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT 
ParentAccount AS AccountNumber
,TYPE
,LstDepDate AS LastDepDate
FROM MBtable
WHERE ProcessDate = 20200430
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
Acct.AccountNumber
, Acct.ABCat AS Cat
, Acct.fName AS FirstName
, Acct.lName AS LastName
, Acct.Age AS Age
, o.Type, o.OFirstLoginDate
, o.OLastLoginDate
, m.Type
, m.LstDepDate AS LastDepDate
FROM 
table1 AS Acct 
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
Online.Account AS AccountNumber
, Online.TYPE
, Online.OBFLDate AS OFirstLoginDate
, Online.OBLLDate AS OLastLoginDate
FROM OBtable AS Online
WHERE Online.DataDate=20200430 
And Online.OBFLDate Is Not Null
)
AS o 
ON Acct.AccountNumber = o.AccountNumber
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
ParentAccount AS AccountNumber
, TYPE
, LstDepDate AS LastDepDate
FROM MBtable
WHERE ProcessDate = 20200430 
AND FDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY LDate DESC
) 
AS m 
ON Acct.AccountNumber = m.AccountNumber
WHERE Acct.Cat IN (9,12,16,17)
 AND Acct.DataDate=20200430 
AND Acct.Status = 'Open';
```

Comment: Maybe not the only problem (so just a comment), but it jumped out at me that you can't have an ORDER BY inside that 2nd subquery. Otherwise, you need to be a lot more specific about what's wrong than "doesn't work".

Comment: Also, instead of `WHERE Acct.Cat=9 OR ... OR ...` you can say `WHERE Acct.Cat IN (9,12,16,17)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't give details on the meaning of "does not work".  Still I think your case can be a good candidate for the usage of "outer apply", if you use MS SQL Server.
[Real life example, when to use OUTER / CROSS APPLY in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275132/real-life-example-when-to-use-outer-cross-apply-in-sql)