# Select distinct list of all elements x of all records in sql xquery

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

Below query expression:

```
SELECT distinct xmlCol.value('(//interest/@id)[1]','nvarchar(64)') FROM table1
```

Returns a list of *id* of **first** *interest* element of all records.

But an xml may contains **multiple** *interest* elements.

So, how to get a distinct list of all *interest* elements of all records in sql xquery ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select distinct T.N.value('.','nvarchar(64)')
from table1
  cross apply xmlCol.nodes('//interest/@id') as T(N)
```