# SQL Query Get Rows Where Xml All Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

This is probably not bad, I'm just not sure how to best phrase the question.

I have Xml Like

```
<Names>
  <Name Language="English">
    <Value></Value>
    <FirstName />
    <MiddleName />
    <LastName />
    <IsPrimary>True</IsPrimary>
  </Name>
</Names>
```

Where (Names) can have many (Name).  I need to get rows in which there are more than one  (which I already have accomplished) and where all (Value) (which is the concatenated first/middle/last) are all distinct.

So essentially I need to ensure all (Value) are unique.  I'm not sure how to select distinct within xml.

Thankyou for your help

Comment: You would need to write some Linq to XML,  check out this link here. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/42dbad3c-9fb2-4f18-b4ef-46f0930e74ef/

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? In `C#` or `T-SQL`?

Comment: trying to do it in T-SQL

Comment: Woops I must have missed TSQL I apologize I thought this was in C#.

Comment: I tagged C# out of habit my fault

Comment: All good, I think you even mentioned it I just looked over.  Here is a post but I am not sure its quite what you are looking for but seems similar.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511461/select-distinct-list-of-all-elements-x-of-all-records-in-sql-xquery

Comment: I saw that, he's looking for a list of the node names, where as i need to compare the values.  The title of that one was misleading

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample code that outputs the raw details in the first query and the distinct values in the second query.  The first query will help you validate the results of the second query.  The following is a [link to a SQL Fiddle for this solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42ef5/2).

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (XmlString XML);

INSERT INTO #Temp (XmlString)
VALUES 
    ('<Names>
      <Name Language="English">
        <Value></Value>
        <FirstName>Hello Goodbye</FirstName>
        <MiddleName />
        <LastName />
        <IsPrimary>True</IsPrimary>
      </Name>
      <Name Language="English">
        <Value></Value>
        <FirstName>Hello</FirstName>
        <MiddleName />
        <LastName>Goodbye</LastName>
        <IsPrimary>True</IsPrimary>
      </Name>
      <Name Language="English">
        <Value></Value>
        <FirstName>Hello</FirstName>
        <MiddleName />
        <LastName>Goodbye</LastName>
        <IsPrimary>True</IsPrimary>
      </Name>
      <Name Language="English">
        <Value></Value>
        <FirstName>Hello</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>There</MiddleName>
        <LastName>Goodbye</LastName>
        <IsPrimary>True</IsPrimary>
      </Name>
      <Name Language="English">
        <Value></Value>
        <FirstName>No</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>You</MiddleName>
        <LastName>Don''t</LastName>
        <IsPrimary>True</IsPrimary>
      </Name>
    </Names>'), 
    ('<Names>
      <Name Language="English">
        <Value></Value>
        <FirstName>Another</FirstName>
        <MiddleName />
        <LastName>Record</LastName>
        <IsPrimary>True</IsPrimary>
      </Name>
      <Name Language="English">
        <Value></Value>
        <FirstName>No</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>You</MiddleName>
        <LastName>Don''t</LastName>
        <IsPrimary>True</IsPrimary>
      </Name>
    </Names>');

SELECT FirstName = NULLIF(SomeNames.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '')
    , MiddleName = NULLIF(SomeNames.value('(MiddleName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '')
    , LastName = NULLIF(SomeNames.value('(LastName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '')
FROM #Temp src (NOLOCK) 
CROSS APPLY XmlString.nodes('/Names/Name') AS ShreddedXml (SomeNames);

SELECT DISTINCT FirstName = REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(CONCAT(NULLIF(SomeNames.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), ''), ' ', NULLIF(SomeNames.value('(MiddleName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), ''), ' ', NULLIF(SomeNames.value('(LastName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '')))), '  ', ' ')
FROM #Temp src (NOLOCK) 
CROSS APPLY XmlString.nodes('/Names/Name') AS ShreddedXml (SomeNames);
```