# Combine 2 SQL Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to combine the following 2 SELECT statements, so that the result of the second statement is present as a column in every row of the first select.

```
SELECT MEM.Id,
   EN.artistName,
   EN.dateAdded,
   EN.voteStatus,
   ES.enterNextRound,
   ES.notified,
   ES.voted,
   GR.genre,
   ES.entrantId AS bandID
FROM recMembers AS MEM
LEFT JOIN recEntrantStatus AS ES
   ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeId
LEFT JOIN recEntrants AS EN
   ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id
LEFT JOIN recGenre AS GR
   ON EN.genreId = GR.Id
WHERE MEM.Id = @memberId
   AND ES.roundId = 2

SELECT COUNT(enterNextRound) 
FROM recEntrantStatus
WHERE enterNextRound = 1
  AND roundId = 2
  AND entrantId = ES.entrantId
```

Where 'ES.entrantId' is taken from the current row accessed in the first select.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`OUTER APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT MEM.Id, 
  EN.artistName, 
  EN.dateAdded, 
  EN.voteStatus, 
  ES.enterNextRound,
  ES.notified, 
  ES.voted, 
  GR.genre, 
  ES.entrantId AS bandID, 
  src.CountEnterNextRound
FROM recMembers AS MEM
LEFT JOIN recEntrantStatus AS ES
  ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeId
LEFT JOIN recEntrants AS EN
  ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id
LEFT JOIN recGenre AS GR
  ON EN.genreId = GR.Id
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT COUNT(enterNextRound) CountEnterNextRound
  FROM recEntrantStatus
  WHERE enterNextRound = 1
    AND roundId = 2
    AND entrantId = @memberId
) src
WHERE MEM.Id = @memberId
  AND ES.roundId = 2
```

Based on your edit, have you tried:

```
SELECT MEM.Id,
   EN.artistName,
   EN.dateAdded,
   EN.voteStatus,
   ES.enterNextRound,
   ES.notified,
   ES.voted,
   GR.genre,
   ES.entrantId AS bandID,
   (SELECT COUNT(enterNextRound) 
    FROM recEntrantStatus
    WHERE enterNextRound = 1
      AND roundId = 2
      AND entrantId = ES.entrantId) CountEnterNextRound
FROM recMembers AS MEM
LEFT JOIN recEntrantStatus AS ES
   ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeId
LEFT JOIN recEntrants AS EN
   ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id
LEFT JOIN recGenre AS GR
   ON EN.genreId = GR.Id
WHERE MEM.Id = @memberId
   AND ES.roundId = 2
```

Or even:

```
SELECT MEM.Id,
   EN.artistName,
   EN.dateAdded,
   EN.voteStatus,
   ES.enterNextRound,
   ES.notified,
   ES.voted,
   GR.genre,
   ES.entrantId AS bandID,
   src.CountEnterNextRound
FROM recMembers AS MEM
LEFT JOIN recEntrantStatus AS ES
   ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeId
LEFT JOIN recEntrants AS EN
   ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id
LEFT JOIN recGenre AS GR
   ON EN.genreId = GR.Id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT COUNT(enterNextRound) CountEnterNextRound, entrantId
  FROM recEntrantStatus
  WHERE enterNextRound = 1
      AND roundId = 2
  GROUP BY entrantId
) src
  ON ES.entrantId = src.entrantId
WHERE MEM.Id = @memberId
   AND ES.roundId = 2;
```

Comment: Interesting. Ive never come across APPLY before. Any chance you could explain a little as to what is going on here? Thanks.

Comment: @PhillHealey here is a link from MSDN -- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @PhillHealey here is another question on SO with details on `APPLY` -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join

Comment: Interestingly its not much different from the CROSS JOIN below. However APPLY returns a quicker result: cross = 2.964 / Apply = 2.948

Comment: Apologies, Ive realised my second select was incorrect. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Thanks. The 1st is working fine. Ive not tried the 2nd. I dont want to be cheeky, BUT.. I have a 3rd query to stick in there too. Its exactly the same as the 2nd but this counts the 'voted' field instead of 'enterNextRound'. How would this best be tackled?

Comment: @PhillHealey You should be able to just add it in a similar fashion, either as a field in the select list or join to it like my 3rd example

Answer (score 3):

wrap that in a subquery and use `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT MEM.Id,
        EN.artistName,
        EN.dateAdded,
        EN.voteStatus,
        ES.enterNextRound,
        ES.notified,
        ES.voted,
        GR.genre,
        ES.entrantId AS bandID,
        s.totalCount
FROM recMembers AS MEM
        LEFT JOIN recEntrantStatus AS ES
                ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeId
        LEFT JOIN recEntrants AS EN
                ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id
        LEFT JOIN recGenre AS GR
                ON EN.genreId = GR.Id
        CROSS JOIN (
                SELECT COUNT(enterNextRound) totalCount
                FROM recEntrantStatus
                WHERE enterNextRound = 1
                        AND roundId = 2
                        AND entrantId = @memberId
                ) s
WHERE MEM.Id = @memberId
        AND ES.roundId = 2
```

Comment: Interestingly its not much different from the APPLY OUTER above. However APPLY returns a quicker result: cross = 2.964 / Apply = 2.948

Comment: really? it's up to you to decide now? both cross and outer apply yields the same result?

Comment: Yes, I just though it interesting to see which answer gave the quickest results, since they were all valid answers. Thanks.

Comment: hehe try running the query thrice and calculate the average time :D

Comment: Apologies, Ive realised my second select was incorrect. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT MEM.Id, EN.artistName, EN.dateAdded, EN.voteStatus, ES.enterNextRound,
    ES.notified, ES.voted, GR.genre, ES.entrantId AS bandID
    FROM recMembers AS MEM
    LEFT JOIN recEntrantStatus AS ES
    ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeId
    LEFT JOIN recEntrants AS EN
    ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id
    LEFT JOIN recGenre AS GR
    ON EN.genreId = GR.Id
    WHERE MEM.Id = @memberId
    AND ES.roundId = 2
) x
,
(
    SELECT COUNT(enterNextRound) as Total
    FROM recEntrantStatus
    WHERE enterNextRound = 1
    AND roundId = 2
    AND entrantId = @memberId
) y
```

When you do FROM 2 tables with no join, you got a Cartesian product like a cross join. So it should be the same execution time.

This is the implicit way to write it.

Comment: Ive never come across this configuration before. This actually throws and incorrect syntax on the ','.

Comment: @PhillHealey I forgot the alias. Now it should work. I have tried it

Comment: I didnt think this would be the quickest query but it actually ties with the APPLY method given in one of the other answers. Unexpected, for such a simple contruction method.

Comment: @PhillHealey When you do FROM 2 tables with no join, you got a Cartesian product like a cross join. I find it more easy to read like that and I am sure that it works on every db

Comment: Apologies, Ive realised my second select was incorrect. Please see my updated question.