# Select all XML attributes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

I have an XML value list contained in a SQL Table Field that looks like so:

```
<valuelist xmlns="" name="VL_IncCompCondVL">
  <li value="BL" item="BLOCKED" />
  <li value="NK" item="NO KEY" />
  <li value="FL" item="FLOODED" />
  <li value="TD" item="TORN DOWN" />
  <li value="UL" item="UNABLE TO LOCATE" />
</valuelist>
```

I want to be able to create a temp SQL table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #incompleteCode
(
value nvarchar(2),
item nvarchar(20)
)
```

and populate it with all the values/items from the XML so that I can use the temp table to JOIN with another SELECT statement.

```
SELECT Data.value('(/valuelist/li/@item)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Item
                                                    FROM ValueList
                                                    WHERE Name = 'VL_IncCompCondVL'
```

That statement gets me the first one, and if i increment [1] to [2] and so on, i can 1 by 1 select each attribute.  But I have to believe there's a way to just get them all.  I've tried some variations and am just not figuring it out.  I think I need to use the * wildcard somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [`nodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) method:

```
SELECT 
  item.value('.', 'nvarchar(50)') 
FROM 
  ValueList 
  CROSS APPLY data.nodes('/valuelist/li/@item') as T2(item) 
where 
  name='VL_IncCompCondVL'
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join) about `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: I have no idea how that works but it does - perfecly.  And intellisense in SQL Managment Studio doesn't either.  It's confused about item.value and data.nodes.  I must go research the nodes method.  Thank you so much!