# Creating a superset in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, select

I have a query that returns a few columns and some information. I want to hardcode a list, and have each row returned each value from my list.

So, currently my `SELECT` is returning, for example,

```
ID   Name   Value
1    Mike   404
2    John   404
```

And lets say, for example, I wish to add a column to my `SELECT` so that a managers name is also returned with each row. So I have a set of managers, which I want to write myself into the SELECT statement(i.e these are not returned from any external source, I want to hardcode them into my `SELECT`) : {'Steve', 'Bill'}. What I now want returned is :

```
ID   Name   Value   Manager
1    Mike   404     Steve
2    John   404     Steve
1    Mike   404     Bill
2    John   404     Bill
```

Is it possible to do this? If so, how? :)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using `UNION ALL` and [`CROSS APPLY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join) to join them with your rows:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name ,p.Value, x.Col AS Manager
FROM dbo.Persons p
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Col FROM (SELECT 'Steve' UNION ALL SELECT 'Bill')AS T(Col))X
```

If the managers are a comma seperated list you need a split function in SQL-Server 2005, for example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @IDTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(50))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @tempItemList = REPLACE (@tempItemList, ' ', '')
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @IDTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

Now this works:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name ,p.Value, s.Item AS Manager
FROM dbo.Persons p
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split('Steve,Bill', ',')s
```

Result (SQL-Fiddle is down):

```
ID  Name    Value   Manager
1   Mike    404     Steve
2   John    404     Steve
1   Mike    404     Bill
2   John    404     Bill
```

Comment: Great answer and post. Thanks very much. I get the message 'Procedure or function dbo.Split has too many arguments specified.' when I try to run this split function with 3+ arguments - but from a look at the code I can't see why this would be the case; it seems like it should work with >2 arguments. Any idea you know what may be causing this ?

Comment: Never mind; I am a silly boy! Mismatched strings/commas. Thank you :)

Comment: @SimonKiely: The `Split` approach can be used if you have a list of comma separated values as `varchar`. So for example (note that it's a single varchar): `dbo.Split('Steve,Bill', ',')`. The first approach using `UNION ALL` to concatenate each hardcoded manager is used if the values are seperated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the exact result as you want

```
select ID,Name,Value, Manager  from Test
cross join

(select 'Bill' Manager
union
select 'Steve' Manager) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as you state the question

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Name, A.Value, B.Manager FROM
(
SELECT ID, Name, Value FROM MyTable
) A
CROSS JOIN
(
SELECT
 'Steve' Manager
UNION
SELECT
 'Bill' Manager
) B
```

Frankly, Id allways store manager in (its own) table