# SQL Server Conditional JOIN two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 Tables:

```
TableA(IDRem, IDPed, IDOP)
TableB(IDOP, IDPed)
TableC(IDPed, InvoiceDate)
```

I need a select to JOIN the records of TableA and TableC, but there are two possible conditions:

> - IF IDPed on TableA IS NOT NULL, then join directly to TableC by IDPed
> - ID IDPed on TableA IS NULL, then join to TableB by IDOp, and then join TableB to TableC by IDPed

So far i try this:

```
SELECT
    TableA.*
    ,(CASE WHEN TableC.InvoiceDate IS NULL
        THEN TableC2.InvoiceDate
        ELSE TableC.InvoiceDate
    END) AS InvoiceDate
FROM
    TableA
    LEFT JOIN TableC on TableA.IDPed = TableC.IDPed
    LEFT JOIN TableB on TableB.IDOp = TableA.IDOp
    INNER JOIN TableC as TableC2 on TableC2.IDPed = TableB.IDPed
```

The problem with this is that every field o tableA I want to include in the select I need to do a case...when to determine if the origin is tableA or TableA2.

Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For complex joins you are better served in TSQL using cross apply:

[When should I use Cross Apply over Inner Join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join)

```
select IDRem, IDPed, IDOP from TableA a
cross apply(
    select IDOP, IDPed from TableB binner
    where a.IDop = binner.IDop
) b
cross apply(
    select IDPed, InvoiceDate cinner
    where b.IDPed = cinner.IDPed
) c
where ...
```

Strictly psuedo-code but should give you a start.

Comment: mmmm i never use Cross Apply before, can you give a basic sample on how to use it in this case? thanks!

Comment: I've added a quick example (disclaimer I haven't checked it so may not be perfect).

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2005/cross-apply-explained

Comment: first part worked: select * from TableA a
cross apply(
    select IDOp from Tableb b 
    where a.IDOp = b.IDOp
) b but if try to do the second cross i get no results

Comment: I also try the second table with outer cross with no luck

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing both `JOIN`s and use `UNION ALL`

*Edit: As pointed out in the comment by Vladimir Baranov, there's no need to check if `a.IdPed IS NULL` on the first `SELECT` since if it is, the `JOIN` would return no rows.*

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    c.InvoiceDate
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableC c ON c.IdPed = a.IdPed

UNION ALL

SELECT
    a.*,
    c.InvoiceDate
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.IdOp = a.IdOP
INNER JOIN TableC c ON c.IdPed = b.IdPed
WHERE a.IdPed IS NULL
```

Comment: Add to your answer explanation that in the first `SELECT` there is no need for the check `WHERE a.IdPed IS NOT NULL`: when `IDPed` is NULL, the `JOIN` would return no rows, so there is no need to explicitly check for it here. In second `SELECT` the check is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems even more complex that my current attemp, joining twice tableC. I'm looking for a simple answer.

Comment: Hmm, I think this would be faster, especially with the proper index.

Comment: It is not a performance problem. I'm looking for a simple SQL sintaxis. Thanks