# How do I select a given number of rows for one table for each parent primary key in another table in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, iteration

I have two tables in sql.  One is a table of test cases and the other is a table of test runs with a foreign key that links back to a test case.  I want to get the most recent 10 test runs for each test case.  I don't want to loop through if I don't have to, but I don't see any other way to solve this problem.  What is the most effective way to handle this sort of thing in sql server?

Comment: Abul and Roman thanks for the quick reply.  I'm going to try both and let you know the results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea:

```
select
    ...
from <test cases> as tc
    outer apply (
        select top 10 *
        from <test runs> as tr
        where
            tr.<test case id> = tc.<id>
        order by tr.<date time> desc
    ) as tr
```

or, if you just need to get data from  table:

```
;with cte_test_runs as (
   select
        *,
        row-Number() over(partition by <test case id> order by <date time> desc) as rn
    from <test runs>
)
select *
from cte_test_runs
where rn <= 10
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Row No. Use Inner of Left Join as the case may be..

```
Select * from testCase a 
left outer join 
(Select Row_number() over (partition by testcase order by RecentDate desc ) RowNo, *  from TestRuns) b
on a.pk = b.fk
where b.RowNo <=10
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CROSS APPLY to select the top 10 per testCase ordered by date (or anyother ordering criteria).

See the related question 'When should I use Cross Apply over Inner Join?' which explains it better than I can.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139231/1620715

In your case:

```
SELECT * from TestCase T
CROSS APPLY 
( SELECT TOP 10 * from TestRuns R where T.TestCaseId = R.TestCaseId
 order by R.TestDate desc) TopResults
```