# When to cross or join two tables?

Tags: sql

Example 1:

```
SELECT name 
FROM Customer, Order 
WHERE Customer.id = Order.cid
```

Example 2:

```
SELECT name 
FROM Customer JOIN Order 
ON Customer.id = Order.cid
```

What is the difference between these two queries? When should I cross two tables vs JOIN?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1139231/4910880)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both will give you identical result. So there is no real situation to use one over another.

The `comma separated join`, is an `ANSI 89` standard join, `INNER JOIN` is the newer `ANSI 92` standard join.

However `comma separated join` syntax is depreciated we always prefer to use `INNER JOIN` syntax. When you want to `join` more than one table it will be difficult to follow the join conditions in `Where` clause where as   `INNER JOIN` syntax is more readable

Answer (score 1):

**CROSS JOIN** operation is a Cartesian product. Result of **CROSS JOIN** operation
between set A and set B is the superset that contains all values.
Then with operator **WHERE** you are filtering this result set.

**INNER JOIN** operation will try to find rows from both tables that correspond predicate
after keyword ON. That rows will go to the result set.

Practically, SQL engine can choose its own physical implementation **CROSS JOIN** operator.
SQL engine doesn't have to get huge result set and then filter it. SQL engine behaviour will
be similar when using **INNER JOIN** operation.