# SQL 2005 returning unique results with subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a database Table a (EMAILS) where EmailID is the Primary Key

```
EmailID     Email_To     Email_From    Email_Subject    Email_Registered    Email_Read
```

If a user creates an email it is registered in this table.

For example, the user "Dave" who has id 3 sends an email to "John" who has id 4

So this would give

```
EmailID     Email_To     Email_From    Email_Subject    Email_Registered    Email_Read
   10          4             3              TEST        2/23/2016 11:00       False
```

To return results I do this select (joining the user profile database)

```
SELECT PROFILE_1.SellerID, PROFILE_1.Seller_UserName, EMAILS.EmailID, EMAILS.Email_From, EMAILS.Email_To, EMAILS.Email_Subject, 
                  EMAILS.Email_Registered, EMAILS.Email_Read,
                      (SELECT Seller_UserName AS Epr2
                        FROM PROFILE
                        WHERE (SellerID = EMAILS.Email_To)) AS Expr2
FROM PROFILE AS PROFILE_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  EMAILS ON EMAILS.Email_From = PROFILE_1.SellerID
WHERE (EMAILS.Email_From IS NOT NULL) AND (PROFILE_1.Seller_UserName = 'Dave')
ORDER BY EMAILS.Email_Registered DESC
```

So John Replies to Dave's email and it goes into the EMAILS_THREAD table and is registered as

```
EmailThreadID     EmailID     Email_To     Email_From     Email_Registered     Email_Read
      1              10          3             4           2/23/2016 11:05       False
```

What I am trying to do is a select that

SELECTS from EMAILS where Email_From is from Dave and return in the results the top 1 result from EMAIL_THREADS that is sent to Dave (based on Email_Registered) with the same EmailID as the EMAILS.EmailID if there is a entry in EMAIL_THREADS.

So in other words return the result of the EMAIL table and latest corresponding result in the EMAIL_THREADS table if there is one.

I hope this makes sense.

I've tried a ton of combinations and I can't figure this out.

At first I thought it was a subquery or a join or a group by...but i can't seem to nail the select and how it is structured.

Looking for some help.

Here is my last attempt

```
SELECT PROFILE_1.SellerID, PROFILE_1.Seller_UserName, EMAILS.EmailID, EMAILS.Email_From, EMAILS.Email_To, EMAILS.Email_Subject, 
                 EMAILS.Email_Registered, EMAILS.Email_Read,
                      (SELECT Seller_UserName AS Epr2
                        FROM PROFILE
                        WHERE (SellerID = EMAILS.Email_To)) AS Expr2
FROM PROFILE AS PROFILE_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  EMAILS ON EMAILS.Email_From = PROFILE_1.SellerID CROSS JOIN
                      (SELECT TOP (1) EMAILS_THREAD.Email_From, EMAILS_THREAD.Email_To, EMAILS_THREAD.Email_Registered, EMAILS_THREAD.Email_Read
                        FROM EMAILS_THREAD LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                               EMAILS AS EMAILS_1 ON EMAILS_THREAD.EmailID = EMAILS_1.EmailID) AS derivedtbl_1
WHERE (EMAILS.Email_From IS NOT NULL) AND (PROFILE_1.Seller_UserName = 'Dave')
ORDER BY EMAILS.Email_Registered DESC
```

But it's not returning anything from EMAILS_THREADS at all.

Comment: It is a sub-query.   Please post your attempt with a sub-query so that we can debug it.

Comment: Hi Tab, using "Dave" to test.

Comment: Sorry...jepp...I guess you see straight away I am not too experienced here. :)

Comment: Well you don't have any columns from EMAILS_THREADS (derivedtbl_1) in your Select list.  You are only selecting columns from PROFILE_1 and EMAILS.

Comment: Haven't been able to find a solution as yet Tab. I'm not getting the result set from the cte select kindly offered by TheGameiswar.

Comment: I don't want to get involved in debugging his answer.  If you post your latest attempt in your question (fixing the issues I mentioned above), I will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

SELECTS from EMAILS where Email_From is from Dave and return in the results the top 1 result from EMAIL_THREADS that is sent to Dave (based on Email_Registered) with the same EmailID as the EMAILS.EmailID if there is a entry in EMAIL_THREADS.Hope this helps

```
   with cte
as
(select
* from emails 
where email_from=3
)
select * from cte mt --only for dave
outer apply
(
select top 1* from 
emial_threads st where mt.mail_from=st.mail_to ---send to dave
and mt.emailid=st.emailid) b
```

Comment: Hi TheGameiswar! I'm getting Incorrect syntax near keyword CROSS in management studio. Any ideas?

Comment: try now,i missed derived table alias

Comment: Hi, I was just reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join and tried to add an alias (as you have with 'b')...but its the same Incorrect syntax near keyword 'CROSS' and now as well incorrect syntax near 'b'.

Comment: Edited plz see again

Comment: Hi thanks...but I'm a bit confused. I don't get the statement "      with cte" ?

Comment: CTE is a like a view which stores the definition of our SQL for immediate execution purposes

Comment: OK...Its is returning a combined result (that's great!) but it is only returning a result when there is an entry in EMAIL_THREAD with Email_To The problem is as I mentioned that every EMAIL entry may not have an entry in EMAIL_THREAD.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104308/discussion-between-thegameiswar-and-steve).

Comment: seems like the query (Top 1) may be the problem? In that only 1 result is ever returned instead of all results and only the top 1 for each EmailID in Emails_Threads with matching EmailID?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't been able to find a solution to this so I am paying a SQL professional to resolve this for me. Thanks for the input from Tab and The Gameiswar. Much appreciated.