# SQL query aggregate function in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, subquery

I got some question regarding MSSQL statement. So basically this is my SQL query:

```
SELECT table1.col1, avg(datediff(dd, table2.date, table3.date)) as avg_date
INNER JOIN table2
INNER JOIN table3
WHERE avg_date <= ALL
(SELECT table1.col1, avg(datediff(dd, table2.date, table3.date)) as avg_date
INNER JOIN table2
INNER JOIN table3
GROUP BY table1.col1);
```

What I am trying to do is inside the subquery, I am getting the list of average date group by each user. The example data returned are (userName, avg_date):

```
user1  10
user2  20
user3  20
```

Then after that, from the query outside, I need to find the minimum of the average date returned from the sub query. However, by doing this, I am getting and error message as from the query outside, I am comparing 1 column only whereby the subquery is returning 2 columns.

The error message is `An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference`

However, inside my subquery I need the GROUP BY each user so I cannot simply SELECT avg.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The error message is An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference. What I am trying to do is inside the subquery, I am getting a list of average day group by each user. Then in the outer query, I am getting the minimum one from that list. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Yeah it is. But for simplicity I removed it. I even renamed the column name as if I were to use my original table name, it will be very confusing

Comment: The error message is your answer. You cannot do it that way; you need to find a different way. Perhaps a CTE for your inner query; or a simple sub query with the WHERE outside, or ...

Comment: Try using CROSS APPLY instead of JOIN for the derived data. It's a sort of inline CTE.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join) is a discussion on `CROSS APPLY` which might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT table1.col1, avg(datediff(dd, table2.date, table3.date)) as avg_date
INNER JOIN table2
INNER JOIN table3
HAVING avg_date <= (SELECT avg_date from
(SELECT table1.col1, avg(datediff(dd, table2.date, table3.date)) as avg_date
INNER JOIN table2
INNER JOIN table3
GROUP BY table1.col1)
);
```

Alternative:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT table1.col1, avg(datediff(dd, table2.date, table3.date)) as avg_date
    INNER JOIN table2
    INNER JOIN table3
) outer_table
WHERE avg_date <= ALL(SELECT avg_date from(SELECT table1.col1,avg(datediff(dd, table2.date, table3.date)) as avg_date
INNER JOIN table2
INNER JOIN table3
GROUP BY table1.col1));
```

Edited for SQL Server

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT table1.col1, avg(datediff(dd, table2.date, table3.date)) as avg_date
    INNER JOIN table2
    INNER JOIN table3
) outer_table
WHERE avg_date <= ALL(SELECT inner_table.avg_date from
(SELECT table1.col1,avg(datediff(dd, table2.date, table3.date)) as avg_date
INNER JOIN table2
INNER JOIN table3
GROUP BY table1.col1) inner_table);
```

Comment: Sorry but the avg_date column is not recognized. Also, there is a syntax error at the last bracket of second select statement

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try "having" insted of "where" in the outer query.

Comment: I have update the query. Also, added a alternative query. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry but is there some bracket misplaced? The error is highlighting at the last bracket saying Execting ID or AS quoted_id

Comment: You are using this in SQL Server ?

Comment: yeah I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: The query I have given is for Oracle SQL. Will post another answer below for SQL Server. Give me 5 mins.

Comment: I have added for SQL Server. Please check now.

Comment: I have having syntax error at the INNER JOIN part: (SELECT table1.col1,avg(datediff(dd, table2.date, table3.date)) as avg_date
INNER JOIN table2
INNER JOIN table3
GROUP BY table1.col1) inner_table)

Comment: There is indeed errors in your query. Acutally, I just answered what you asked(i.e., where condition). The problem is your join query, it is wrong there should be "on" or "where" condition based on which the join will happen, also add a from keyword before inner join and add table1 as well.

Comment: Sorry I think I missed out one FROM for the inner query, now its working fine for inner query. The problem now is at the SELECT after the ALL. Can you actually wrap it  with the inner query as what you did above?

Comment: Foget to add inner_table.avg_date. Just add that in the SELECT after the ALL.(i.e., WHERE avg_date <= ALL(SELECT inner_table.avg_date from....

Comment: Hmm it did returned me something but it's not the expect output as I think this query perform avg multiple times until it is returning me with -ve value

Comment: So, that means there is something wrong with the logic. I may be able to help you with it over chat that I will be able to do only after one hour or try to debug the logic, execute only the inner query and see what results its returning and so on.