# mssql - retrieve unique values of a column based on another column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with two columns:  `ColumnA`, `ColumnB`,  with rows:

|    A   |    1  |
|    B   |    1  |
|    B   |    2  |
|    C   |    1  |
|    C   |    1  |
|    C   |    1  |
|    A   |    2  |
|    B   |    1  |
|    A   |    2  |
|    A   |    1  |

I would like to write a query that would return all unique values for `ColumnB`, for each unique value of `ColumnA`, where `ColumnA` has more than 1 value in `ColumnB` i.e.

|    A   |    1 |
|    A   |    2 |
|    B   |    1 |
|    B   |    2 |

C   1 should be omitted because there is only one distinct value for ColumnA = 'C'

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything special about column A versus column B - it would appear you could just do `distinct columna,columnb` here.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add the second part of my requirement,  i.e. where ColumnA has more than 1 values in ColumnB

Comment: @PanikosStavrou, You may have to re-write you question. it is a bit vague. for example, if you want to join tableA to TableB what column are you going to use?

Comment: @JonWay there is only one table

Comment: @IvanP I don't want where, for example, A - 1 repeats more than one time. I want where for A I have more than one values (1, 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a simpler approach but this works:

```
SELECT t.ColumnA, t2.ColumnB
FROM ( select ColumnA 
       from dbo.TableName t 
       group by t.ColumnA
       having count(distinct t.ColumnB) > 1) t
CROSS APPLY ( select distinct t2.ColumnB 
              from dbo.TableName t2 
              where t.ColumnA=t2.ColumnA ) t2
```

The first subquery returns all unique `ColumnA` values that have multiple (different) `ColumnB` values. The 2nd subquery returns all *distinct* `ColumnB` values of those `ColumnA`-values with [`CROSS APPLY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM x WHERE ColumnA IN(
    SELECT xd.ColumnA
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA, ColumnB FROM x
    ) xd
    GROUP BY xd.ColumnA HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
)

SELECT y.ColumnA, y.ColumnB
FROM (
    SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  ColumnA) m
    FROM x 
    GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnB
) y
WHERE m > 1
```