# How to achieve CROSS APPLY in NETEZZA?

Tags: sql-server, join, netezza, cross-join, cross-apply

I wanted to share how we can achieve `CROSS APPLY` functionality without using it.[works in `NETEZZA` `SQL`].

***FOLLOWING QUERY USES CROSS APPLY TO RETRIVE LAST 52 WEEK FOF EACH WEEK:***

```
SELECT      t1.col, 
            t3.col          AS col_last52wks
FROM        TABLE1 t1
            CROSS APPLY (
                          SELECT TOP 52 t2.col
                          FROM  TABLE2 t2
                          WHERE t2.col <= t1.col
                          ORDER BY t2.col DESC
                ) t3
--Last 13 Weeks Condition
WHERE t1.col >= minvalue -- RANDOM
AND   t1.col <= maxvalue-- RANDOM
```

We can achieve this with the following modifications in the above code and get rid of the `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT  t1.col,
        t2.col             AS col_last52wks
FROM    TABLE1 t1
        INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
                ON t2.sequencecol BETWEEN (t1.sequencecol - 51) AND t1.sequencecol
WHERE t1.col >= minvalue
AND   t1.col <= maxvalue
```

Comment: `Cross Apply` will return top 10 `tradyrwkcode` from `t2` for each `tradyrwkcode` from `t1`. but `Cross Join` will return only 10 records no matter how many `tradyrwkcode` are present

Comment: Would I be wrong if I say CROSS APPLY works similar to INNER JOIN ?

Comment: Sort of, but they have their own uses. Outer table reference can be referenced inside a `CROSS APPLY` sub select, but in `Inner join` you cannot do the same.

Comment: That'd be the only difference or there are others as well ?

Comment: There are many other differences present as well. Google it..

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join

Comment: Cross apply is similar to inner join but will return a cartesian product related to the main table or whichever you relate it to. Cross join is similar to building a cube where to display any possible combination from both tables

Comment: There is no `CROSS APPLY` in "SQL" - the standard query language. `cross apply` is specific for T-SQL from Microsoft. The equivalent to that in standard SQL is a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`

Answer (score 1):

I use CROSS APPLY for such cases:

When I [split](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) a column data into multiple rows and make "join"s over this splitted data

The statements are as follows in general

```
FROM Table1
CROSS APPLY dbo.UDF_TableFunctionName(Table1Column) as t
```

So, if you are passing a string value to a table function, than you can simply use it as

```
select * from dbo.UDF_TableFunctionName(@strVariable)
```

But if you want to use this function on a row set instead of a single value, then you use CROSS APPLY

CROSS APPLY is useful if you want to return more than 1 column for a row column
For example, in this [table valued function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-table-valued-function-example.aspx), I parse a date column into its date parts and show in the same row

```
select
 o.SalesOrderID, o.OrderDate,
 d.[year], d.[month], d.[day]
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader o
cross apply dbo.udf_ParseDate(o.OrderDate) d
```

And on CROSS APPLY you don't use a join condition following ON
You just pass a column as input parameter to a table-valued function

CROSS JOIN is simply a cartesian of the two tables.
We used to code it without "CROSS JOIN" as follows

```
FROM TableA, TableB
```