# Passing parameters into a Table-Valued Function

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have a TVF which needs 2 parameters a countrycode which is fixed within my general select statement

```
DECLARE @CountryCode as nvarchar(2)
SET @CountryCode = 'GB'
```

and a Date of which there will be many in my Select statement result

My TVF needs to pick up the Countrycode and date at runtime - if that's possible!

```
CREATE function [dbo].[V3_Pricelist_Country_lvl] (@Country as nvarchar(2), @Date as date)
returns table
as
return
SELECT @Country as Country, pl.SKU, pl.[RRP W/O TAX], pl.[BASE PRICE]
FROM V3_PriceList pl 
WHERE pl.Country = @Country and @Date between pl.Date and pl.DateEnd and [DISCONTINUED DATE] is null
```

I have tried to write my calling code as a left join like this

```
left join V3_PriceList_Country_lvl(@CountryCode, a.[Week_ending]) pl on pl.SKU = a.UID
```

but I get the following error message

> The multi-part identifier "a.Week_ending" could not be bound.

If I could fix the date into a Declare variable it would work but the date  will change on every row for every country and SKU.
Apart from a regular Left join to the full V3_PriceList table how can make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `OUTER APPLY`, no left join.

If you want to pass a value from outer table to your UDF as parameter, use `CROSS APPLY/OUTER APPLY` instead of `INNER JOIN/OUTER JOIN`.

Sample:-

```
SELECT ...
FROM [table_name] AS a
OUTER APPLY V3_PriceList_Country_lvl(@CountryCode, a.[Week_ending]) pl
WHERE ...
```

[More info here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join)

Comment: Thanks after a bit of faffing about I also found that it needs to go after all of the other left joins. Read up on the APPLY function here which explains it quite well https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply