# SQL Server CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, cross-apply

I'm trying to add in a `CROSS APPLY` to this query. I've never done one before, but a co-worker suggested it and it seems to make sense. I'm getting a syntax error though. Here's the query:

```
            SELECT
                i.IncidentID,
                i.AccountID,
                i.IncidentTypeID,
                i.IncidentStateID,
                i.CreateDate,
                i.LastModifyDate,
                i.LastModifyUser,
                (
                    SELECT
                        COUNT(*) 
                    FROM
                        Actions a
                    WHERE
                        a.IncidentID = i.IncidentID
                ) AS ActionCount
            CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT TOP 1
                    a.IncidentStateID,
                    a.LastModifyDate
                FROM Actions a
                WHERE a.IncidentID = i.IncidentID
                ORDER BY a.LastModifyDate DESC
            )
            FROM
                Incidents i
            WHERE i.IncidentTypeID = 44
            AND i.IncidentStateID = 7
            AND i.CreateDate >= ?
            AND i.CreateDate < ?
```

Ultimately I need to get the `a.IncidentStateID` and a.LastModifyDate of the most recent "Action" that has an incident. This is why it is ordered by DESC and just selecting the top 1. Anyone see the syntax issue. The error just says `General error: 20018 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.`. If I remove that it moves on to another piece of syntax and so on.

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139231/9236062

Comment: It's not clear to me why CROSS APPLY might be needed here.  Is there a relationship between `Incidents` and `Actions`?  CROSS APPLY will not give you the most recent Action for an Incident.  CROSS APPLY is used when there is no key field shared between tables.

Comment: There is a relationship. I'm honestly not sure. My co-worker said it was the way to go. I do know that there is a One-to-Many relationship between Incidents and Actions, but as I'm only grabbing the most recent Action, duplicates would not be an issue. Definitely considering going another route.

Comment: I think you may be looking for a CTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Apply` should go after `from` clause :

```
SELECT i.IncidentID, i.AccountID, i.IncidentTypeID,
        t.IncidentStateID, i.CreateDate, i.LastModifyDate, t.LastModifyUser,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM Actions a
         WHERE a.IncidentID = i.IncidentID
        ) AS ActionCount
FROM Incidents i CROSS APPLY( 
     SELECT TOP (1) a.IncidentStateID, a.LastModifyDate
     FROM Actions a
     WHERE a.IncidentID = i.IncidentID
     ORDER BY a.LastModifyDate DESC
     ) t
WHERE i.IncidentTypeID = 44 AND i.IncidentStateID = 7 AND 
      i.CreateDate >= ? AND i.CreateDate < ?;
```

Comment: Ah. Thank you! I had it there and it wasn't working. It works now. What is the `t` for?

Comment: Its an alias just how you have `Actions a` in your query.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!