# Using multiple and interdepended CROSS-APPLY across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, inner-join, cross-apply

How can I use either `CROSS APPLY` (or `INNER JOIN`) to get data from one table based on the values in other tables?

I.e. I have the following tables:

Table Descriptions:

| ProdID | Description | TrackNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 361 | Test 1 | 499 |
| 388 | Test 2 | 003 |
| 004 |  | 5599 |
| 238 | Test 3 | 499 |
| 361 | Test 10 | 555 |
| 004 | Test 40 | 555 |

Table Products:

| ProdID | ProductName | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 361 | P1 | 5.00 |
| 388 | P2 | 5.00 |
| 004 | P3 | 12.00 |
| 238 | P4 | 6.00 |
| 515 | P5 | 7.00 |
| 636 | P6 | 7.00 |
| 775 | P7 | 7.00 |
| 858 | P8 | 8.00 |

Table Invoices:

| ProdID | TrackNum | InvoiceID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 361 | 499 | 718 |
| 388 | 199 | 718 |
| 004 | 499 | 718 |
| 238 | 499 | 718 |
| 361 | 555 | 333 |
| 004 | 555 | 444 |
| 361 | 111 | 444 |
| 388 | 222 | 333 |
| 616 | 116 | 565 |
| 717 | 116 | 565 |
| 361 | 003 | 221 |
| 388 | 003 | 221 |
| 004 | 5599 | 728 |

What I need my query to do is to:

1. Go into Invoices table first, and get only records that matches specified InvoiceID and TrackNum;
2. Then go into Products table and get **only** rows that have **matches** on **ProdID** between the data I pulled out in Step #1 and the data existis in the Products table.
3. Then finally get all columns from the Descriptions table, but only for the rows which I got in the Step #2 and which matches on ProdID.

What I need to have at the end is something like this (if I get more columns that is fine, but I do not want to get more rows):

| ProdID | Description | TrackNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 361 | Test 1 | 499 |
| 004 |  | 5599 |
| 238 | Test 3 | 499 |

I have following query (and I have tried using `INNER JOIN` and `CROSS APPLY`) - but it returns me more rows than I need:

```
SELECT * FROM [Descriptions] AS [DES] 
CROSS APPLY
(
    select * from [Invoices] AS [INV] where [INV].[TrackNum] = '499' AND [INV].[InvoiceID] = '718'
) [INV]
CROSS APPLY 
    (
        select * from [Products] AS [GP] 
        WHERE [GP].[ProdID] = [INV].[ProdID]
    ) [GP2]
WHERE 
[DES].[ProdID] = [GP2].[ProdID]
order by [DES].[ProdID] asc
```

Comment: You have no conditions, anywhere, stating which Description record associates to which Invoices record. So, you're applying all of the invoices you find, to every single description.

Comment: This might help...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join

Comment: Looks like you might be able to use [where exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of a join or cross apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  invoices   AS i
LEFT JOIN
  descriptions   AS d
    ON  d.prodid = i.prodid
    AND d.tracknum = i.tracknum -- you don't have this, but I think it's required.
LEFT JOIN
  products   AS p
    ON  p.prodid = i.prodid
WHERE
      i.invoiceid = 718
  AND i.tracknum = 499
ORDER BY
  i.prodid
```

One thing that concerns me is that both the invoices and descriptions have a column named `tracknum`, but your query and expected data indicate that you **don't** want to include that in the join?  That's very confusing and either a poor column name, or a mistake in your query and example results.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for the edit, but I had caps to emphasise the word Don't ;) Changed to bold instead...  (Feel free to correct typos though, I am doing this on my phone, so it's very prone to smelling pistakes.)

Comment: That is the delema, I need the ProdID = 004 without a Description (even though it is TrackNum = 5599) to be in my final output. But if I use AND d.tracknum = i.tracknum - then this row will not be in the final, and if I do not use this - it will return too many rows :(

Comment: Thanks, folks! I missed the LEFT part. That is what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you describe you want the following, start with your `Invoices` table and a where clause to get the right rows, then join on `Products` and `Descriptions`.

I'm also guessing that you want to match the `Description` on `TrackNum`? Since it appears you have a unique `Description` per `ProdId`/`TrackNum` combination.

```
select [INV].[ProdID], [DES].[Description], [INV].[TrackNum]
from [Invoices] as [INV]
inner join [Products] as [GP] on [GP].[ProdID] = [INV].[ProdID]
inner join [Descriptions] on [DES].[ProdID] = [GP].[ProdID] and [DES].[TrackNum] = [INV].[TrackNum]
where [INV].[TrackNum] = '499' AND [INV].[InvoiceID] = '718'
order by [DES].[ProdID] asc;
```

Note: You normally only use a 'CROSS APPLY' for queries where you want to run/evaluate something per row in your main table.

Comment: Might want to make it `select distinct [INV].[ProdID], [DES].[Description], [INV].[TrackNum]`, to ensure no duplicates from the joins

Comment: @David784 I'm not a fan of distinct, IMO using `distinct` means one hasn't designed the query correctly. If duplicate products are possible the I'd group. But will wait to see what OP says.

Comment: Might need to be LEFT JOIN as the invoices have tracknum 499 but one description has tracknum 5599

Comment: @MatBailie I'm not going to try and second guess OP... they can clarify.

Answer (score -1):

In this case the Inner Join is sufficient. You don't need to use Cross Apply

Comment: Answers should fully answer the question, not just give tips which are more suited to comments.